# Spring OneToMany relation with composite key to another with a composite key

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a ManyToOne relation between 2 classes (Chapter & Camera). A chapter object contains many Camera objects.

The problem is my parent class (Chapter) already has a composite key.

Chapter composite key:

```
@Embeddable
public class ChapterKey implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "Chapter_ID", nullable = false)
private int chapterID;

@Column(name = "Operation_FK", nullable = false)
private int operationFK;
}
```

Chapter class:

```
@Entity
public class Chapter implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private ChapterKey chapterKey;

  @Column(name="Chapter_Name")
  private String chapterName;

  @Column(name="Chapter_Description")
  private String chapterDescription;

  @Column(name="Chapter_View_Range")
  private int chapterViewRangeInterval;

  @Column(name="Chapter_Video_Length")
  private int chapterVideoLength;
 }
```

Camera key:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class CameraKey implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "Camera_ID", nullable = false)
  private int cameraID;

  @Column(name = "Chapter_FK", nullable = false)
  private int chapterFK;

  @Column(name = "Operation_FK", nullable = false)
  private int operationFK;
}
```

Camera class:

```
@Entity
public class Camera implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private CameraKey cameraKey;

  @Column(name="Camera_Description")
  private String cameraDescription;

  @Column(name="Camera_Usage")
  private int cameraUsage;

  @Column(name="Video_URL")
  private String videoURL;
}
```

My question is, how do i make a OneToMany relationship between those 2 classes?

Answer (score 0):

This is ER for `pk(camera_id)` & `pk(chapter_id,operation_fk)` problem

[image]

This is a Chapter class.

```
    @Entity
public class Camera implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "camera_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer cameraId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "camera_description", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String cameraDescription;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "camera_usage", nullable = false)
    private int cameraUsage;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "video_url", nullable = false)
    private int videoUrl;

    @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_fk", referencedColumnName = "chapter_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Chapter chapterFk;

    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_fk", referencedColumnName = "operation_fk", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Chapter operationFk;  

}
```

this is ChapterPK.class that define primary key of your chapter class. it has composite primary key.

```
    @Embeddable
public class ChapterPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_id", nullable = false)
    private int chapterId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "operation_fk", nullable = false)
    private int operationFk;

}
```

finally camera.class

```
@Entity
public class Chapter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ChapterPK chapterPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)

    @Column(name = "chapter_name", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String chapterName;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_description", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String chapterDescription;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_Vvew_range", nullable = false)
    private int chapterVvewrange;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_video_length", nullable = false)
    private int chapterVideoLength;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "chapterFk", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Camera> cameraCollection;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "operationFk", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Camera> cameraCollection1;

}
```

In here I use two way binding in both chapter and camera classes. if you are using composite primary key. you have to manage additional embedded primary key object.

Comment: Before my code is not correct. add getters and setters for code and check it

Comment: addition this is generated code from Netbeans. If ER is ok then answer is 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks alot, your answer wans't exactly what is was looking for but you pushed me in the right direction. With some few tweaks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This answer for chapter side `pk(Chapter_ID, Operation_FK)` and camera side `pk(camera_id,chapter_fk,operation_fk)`

ER for is below.

[image]

Chapter.class is

```
@Entity
public class Chapter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ChapterPK chapterPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_name", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String chapterName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_description", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String chapterDescription;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_Vvew_range", nullable = false)
    private int chapterVvewrange;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_video_length", nullable = false)
    private int chapterVideoLength;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "chapter")
    private Collection<Camera> cameraCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "chapter1")
    private Collection<Camera> cameraCollection1;


}
```

ChapterPK.class

```
@Embeddable
public class ChapterPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_id", nullable = false)
    private int chapterId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "operation_fk", nullable = false)
    private int operationFk;



}
```

Camera.class

```
@Entity
public class Camera implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected CameraPK cameraPK;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "camera_description", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String cameraDescription;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "camera_usage", nullable = false)
    private int cameraUsage;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "video_url", nullable = false)
    private int videoUrl;

    @JoinColumn(name = "chapter_fk", referencedColumnName = "chapter_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Chapter chapter;

    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_fk", referencedColumnName = "operation_fk", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Chapter chapter1;



}
```

CameraPK.class

```
@Embeddable
public class CameraPK implements Serializable {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "camera_id", nullable = false)
    private int cameraId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "chapter_fk", nullable = false)
    private int chapterFk;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "operation_fk", nullable = false)
    private int operationFk;



}
```

In here both side has two way binding.

Comment: this one has two composite key.  different from another answer. can you suggest correct answer will you get.